# Can emacs show an image in a zip archieve file in org-mode

Tags: image, emacs, zip, archive, org-mode

In emacs org-mode with iimage-mode enabled, it can show an inline image from a relative file path, like:
[[file:images/foo.jpg]]

What I want is: how can it shows an image locates in an zip archive, like this:
**[[file:images.zip/foo.jpg]]**
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's a related question on emacs stackexchange which should help you. The question was [how to display pdf images in org mode](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/401/115). The solution can be modified for you use case where it deals with .zip instead of .pdf and it calls `unzip` binary via `shell-command` instead of `convert`.

Comment: yes, by following that answer, my goal has achieved  almostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules for this to work:

- If you have a zip file `zippedimg.zip` containing the image `myimage.png`, you should reference it in the org mode file as `[[./zippedimg_zip/myimage.png]]`. Note that I have replaced the `.` in `zippedimg.zip` to `_`.
- The reason for doing so is that I am creating the same directory as mentioned within the `[[` and `]]`. But as the `zippedimg.zip` file exists, emacs does not allow creating a directory with the same name. So for `zippedimg.zip` file, I am extracting ONLY the image in it **while preserving the path inside the zip** into a `zippedimg_zip` directory.

Here is a mininum working org file to test it out:

```org
#+TITLE: Image from archive
#+STARTUP: inlineimages

#+NAME: fig:myimage
#+HEADER: :extractfromarchive t
# The below caption line is optional
#+CAPTION: My image myimage.png inside ./zippedimg.zip
[[./zippedimg_zip/myimage.png]]
```

Here is the code you need to put somewhere in your emacs init:

```el
;; Execute the `modi/org-include-img-from-archive' function just before saving the file
(add-hook 'before-save-hook #'modi/org-include-img-from-archive)
;; Execute the `modi/org-include-img-from-archive' function before processing the
;; file for export
(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'modi/org-include-img-from-archive)

(defun modi/org-include-img-from-archive (&rest ignore)
  "Extract image files from the archive files. Only .zip files are supported
as of now.

Only looks at #HEADER: lines that have \":extractfromarchive t\".
This function does nothing if not in org-mode, so you can safely
add it to `before-save-hook'."
  (interactive)
  (when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min)) ; go to the beginning of the buffer
      (while (search-forward-regexp
              "^\\s-*#\\+HEADER:.*\\s-:extractfromarchive\\s-+t"
              nil :noerror)
        (let (;; only .zip supported as of now
              (search-expr "\\[\\[\\(.*?\\)_zip/\\(.*?\\)\\([^/]+\\..*\\)\\]\\]")
              arc-file
              path-in-arc-file
              img-file img-file-full-path
              dest-dir dest-dir-full-path
              cmd)
          ;; Keep on going on to the next line till it finds a line with
          ;; `[[./path/to/zip-file/path/inside/zip/to/the/image]]'
          (while (progn
                   (forward-line 1)
                   (or (not (looking-at search-expr))
                       (eobp))))
          (when (looking-at search-expr)
            (setq arc-file (expand-file-name
                            (concat (match-string-no-properties 1) ".zip")))
            (setq path-in-arc-file (match-string-no-properties 2))
            (setq img-file (match-string-no-properties 3))
            (setq dest-dir (concat "./" (file-name-base arc-file)
                                   "_zip/" path-in-arc-file))
            (setq dest-dir-full-path (concat (file-name-sans-extension arc-file)
                                             "_zip/" path-in-arc-file))
            (setq img-file-full-path (expand-file-name img-file dest-dir))
            ;; (message (concat "arc-file: %s\npath-in-arc-file: %s\n"
            ;;                  "img-file: %s\nimg-file-full-path: %s\n"
            ;;                  "dest-dir: %s\ndest-dir-full-path: %s")
            ;;          arc-file path-in-arc-file
            ;;          img-file img-file-full-path
            ;;          dest-dir dest-dir-full-path)

            (when (file-newer-than-file-p arc-file img-file-full-path)
              ;; This block is executed only if arc-file is newer than
              ;; img-file-full-path
              ;; or if img-file does not exist
              ;; https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html
              (when (file-exists-p dest-dir-full-path)
                (delete-directory dest-dir-full-path t t))
              (make-directory dest-dir-full-path t)
              (setq cmd (format "unzip -j %s %s%s -d ./%s."
                                arc-file path-in-arc-file img-file
                                (concat (file-name-base arc-file) "_zip/"
                                        path-in-arc-file)))
              (message "%s" cmd)
              (shell-command cmd)
              (shell-command (concat "touch " img-file-full-path)))))))))
```

Comment: it works fine. note that a litter difference is that you extract image file to the same path as the archive file, and I did above is put it in a temporary directory.

Comment: The biggest difference is that it supports a file location like `[[./somedir/zipfile_zip/dir-in-zip/img.png]]` where the zip file location is `./somedir/zipfile.zip`. Here the zip file name need not be a constant like `arc.zip`. The benefit of extracting at the same location is that the image file include will work as normal image include, the zip file won't be re-extracted if the zip file is older than the already extracted image.

Comment: As and when I get chance, I am working on optimizing this function more in my git: https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/elisp/org-include-img-from-archive/org-include-img-from-archive.el The eventual goal is to support different archive formats.

Comment: That's great. By the way I'll explain why I want to extract zipped file to another place: usually, I save by org documents(with images) into a usb flash disk, and backup them to another disk at regular intervals. as the copy speed becomes slow when deal with a number of small files, I put the images into one zip file to reduce file number. That's why I want see them in org files but not in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

thanks [kaushalmodi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1219634/kaushalmodi),
below is what I did, by following the answer in this question [how to display pdf images in org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/401/115). As this is the first time I do lisp programming, the code maybe not well designed.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'modi/org-include-img-from-zip)
(defun modi/org-include-img-from-zip (&rest ignore)
  "extract images from zip an archive.
  This function does nothing if not in org-mode."
(interactive)
(when (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
(save-excursion
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (search-forward-regexp
          "^\\s-*#\\+STARTUP:.*\\s-convertfromzip"
          nil 'noerror)
    (let* (filenoext imgext imgfile imgfilename zipfile imgpath cmd)
      (setq zipfile "arc.zip")
      ;; Keep on going on to the next line till it finds a line with
      ;; `[[FILE]]'
      (while (progn
               (forward-line 1)
               (not (looking-at "\\[\\[\\(.*\\)\\.\\(.*\\)\\]\\]"))))
      (when (looking-at "\\[\\[file:\\(.*\\)\\.\\(.*\\)\\]\\]")
        (setq filenoext (match-string-no-properties 1))
        (setq imgext (match-string-no-properties 2))
        (setq imgpath (concat filenoext "." imgext))
        (setq imgfile (expand-file-name (concat filenoext "." imgext)))
        (setq imgfilename (file-name-nondirectory imgfile))
        (when (string= (substring imgpath 0 1) "~")
          (setq imgpath (concat "%HOME%" (substring imgpath 1 nil)))
          (setq imgpath (file-name-directory imgpath))
            (setq cmd (concat "7z e " zipfile " -y -o"imgpath " " imgfilename " " imgfilename ))
            (with-temp-buffer (shell-command cmd t))
          )
        ))))))
```

Comment: Turns out the zip needed a more robust solution; I have added my answer. That's great that you jumped into this as your first elisp experiment. Keep it going! :)